Getting 503 Service Unavailable 30.36 s 217 B after publish code on AWS Lambda
I have right a code which is below it working fine in local but after publishing it on Lambda and link with API Gateway I'm getting error of 503 Service Unavailable 30.36 s 217 B. I know its need to be optimized but I am stuck in how to do that.
I need a solution for it. How can I get fast data that will get from API as well?
public class Function
{
    private readonly FireStoreHelper fireStoreHelper = new();
    private GETByBusinessId byBusiness = new();
    private List<Dictionary<string, object>>? properties;
    private HttpStatus status;
    /// <summary>
    /// A simple function that takes a string and does a ToUpper
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="input">The event for the Lambda function handler to process.</param>
    /// <param name="context">The ILambdaContext that provides methods for logging and describing the Lambda environment.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
   
    public async Task<string> FunctionHandler(JsonObject input, ILambdaContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(input.ToString());
            string? PublickKey = string.Empty;
            if (root?.headers != null)
            {
                PublickKey = Convert.ToString(root?.headers.Key != null ? root?.headers.Key : root?.headers.Key) ?? null;
            }
            if (PublickKey != null && PublickKey.Equals(common.PublicKey))
            {
                var ById = new GETById();

                if (root?.body != null)
                    ById = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GETById>(root.body);
                else
                    ById = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GETById>(input.ToString());

                if (ById != null && ById.Id > 0)
                {
                    if (ById.Id != 28 && ById.Id != 34)
                        ById.Id = 28;
                    List<MenuCategoryVM> ret = new List<MenuCategoryVM>();
                    
                    var menuCategories = await GetMenuCategories(ById.Id);

                    List<ModelLibrary.FireStore.MenuDishPropertiesGroups>? MenuDishPropertiesGroupList = new();

                    if (menuCategories != null && menuCategories.Count > 0)
                    {
                        GETMenuById menuById;
                        foreach (var cat in menuCategories.Where(x => x.BusinessDetailId == ById.Id && !(bool)x.IsDeleted).OrderBy(x => x.DisplayOrder))
                        {
                            MenuCategoryVM menuCategory = new MenuCategoryVM()
                            {
                                BusinessDetailId = cat.BusinessDetailId,
                                DisplayOrder = cat.DisplayOrder,
                                Name = cat.Name,
                                Description = cat.Description,
                                Id = cat.Id,
                                ImagePath = cat.ImagePath,
                                TopCategoryName = cat.TopCategoryName,
                                IsDeleted = cat.IsDeleted,
                                MenuItems = new List<MenuItemVM>()
                            };

                            var MenuItem = await GetMenuItems(cat.Id);
                            if (MenuItem != null && MenuItem.Count > 0)
                            {
                                foreach (var menuItem in MenuItem.Where(x => x.MenuCategoryId == cat.Id).OrderBy(x => x.DisplayOrder))
                                {
                                    var newmenuItem = new MenuItemVM()
                                    {
                                        MenuCategoryId = cat.Id,
                                        DisplayOrder = menuItem.DisplayOrder,
                                        Name = menuItem.Name,
                                        Description = menuItem.Description,
                                        Price = menuItem.Price,
                                        DiscountOff = menuItem.DiscountOff,
                                        Id = menuItem.Id,
                                        MenuItemModels = new List<MenuItemModelVM>(),
                                        ImagePath = menuItem.ImagePath,
                                        Spicyness = menuItem.Spicyness,
                                        ContainEggs = menuItem.ContainEggs,
                                        IsChefSpecial = menuItem.IsChefSpecial,
                                        IsMustTry = menuItem.IsMustTry,
                                        IsRecommended = menuItem.IsRecommended,
                                        IsSeasonal = menuItem.IsSeasonal,
                                        Vegetarian = menuItem.Vegetarian,
                                        OriginalPrice = menuItem.OriginalPrice,
                                        IsDisabled = menuItem.IsDisabled,
                                        DisabledUpto = menuItem.DisabledUpto,
                                        TaxIds = menuItem.TaxIds,
                                        DefaultToppings = menuItem.DefaultToppings,
                                        AvailableForCollection = menuItem.AvailableForCollection,
                                        AvailableForDelivery = menuItem.AvailableForDelivery
                                    };
                                    var MenuItemPropertiesList = await GetMenuItemProperties(menuItem.Id);
                                    if (MenuItemPropertiesList != null && MenuItemPropertiesList.Count > 0)
                                    {
                                        foreach (var menuItemPro in MenuItemPropertiesList.Where(x => x.IdMenuItem == menuItem.Id).OrderBy(x => x.DisplayOrder))
                                        {
                                            var newmenuItemPro = new MenuItemPropertyVM()
                                            {
                                                DisplayOrder = menuItemPro.DisplayOrder,
                                                Id = menuItemPro.Id,
                                                IdMenuItem = menuItemPro.IdMenuItem,
                                                Name = menuItemPro.Name,
                                                Price = menuItemPro.Price,
                                                OriginalPrice = menuItemPro.OriginalPrice,
                                                DiscountOffer = menuItemPro.DiscountOffer,
                                                MenuItemPropertyModels = new List<MenuItemPropertyModelVM>(),
                                                IsDisabled = menuItem.IsDisabled,
                                                DisabledUpto = menuItem.DisabledUpto,
                                                ImageNameForSize = menuItemPro.ImageNameForSize
                                            };
                                           
                                            var MenuItemPropertyModelsList = await GetMenuItemPropertyModels(menuItemPro.Id);
                                            if (MenuItemPropertyModelsList != null && MenuItemPropertyModelsList.Count > 0)
                                            {
                                                foreach (var meniItemProModel in MenuItemPropertyModelsList.Where(x => x.MenuItemPropertyId == menuItemPro.Id).OrderBy(x => x.DisplayOrder))
                                                {
                                                    var NewProModel = new MenuItemPropertyModelVM()
                                                    {
                                                        DisplayOrder = meniItemProModel.DisplayOrder,
                                                        Id = meniItemProModel.Id,
                                                        ItemId = meniItemProModel.ItemId,
                                                        MenuItemPropertyId = meniItemProModel.MenuItemPropertyId,
                                                        ItemType = meniItemProModel.ItemType,
                                                        Label = meniItemProModel.Label,
                                                        MaxQty = meniItemProModel.MaxQty,
                                                        MaxSelectionPerItem = meniItemProModel.MaxSelectionPerItem,
                                                        MinQty = meniItemProModel.MinQty,
                                                        Name = meniItemProModel.Name
                                                    };
                                                    if (NewProModel.ItemType == "Option")
                                                    {
                                                        if (MenuDishPropertiesGroupList == null && MenuDishPropertiesGroupList.Count == 0)
                                                        {
                                                            MenuDishPropertiesGroupList = await fireStoreHelper.getDocumentList<ModelLibrary.FireStore.MenuDishPropertiesGroups>(collectionNames.MenuDishPropertiesGroups);
                                                        }
                                                        MenuDishPropertiesGroups? option = new();
                                                        if (MenuDishPropertiesGroupList == null && MenuDishPropertiesGroupList.Count > 0)
                                                            option = MenuDishPropertiesGroupList.Where(x => x.Id == Convert.ToInt32(meniItemProModel.ItemId)).FirstOrDefault();

                                                        if (option != null)
                                                        {
                                                            NewProModel.OptionItem = new MenuDishPropertiesGroupVM()
                                                            {
                                                                BusinessDetailId = option.BusinessDetailId,
                                                                DishPropertyGroup = option.DishPropertyGroup,
                                                                DishPropertyGroupDisplayName = option.DishPropertyGroupDisplayName,
                                                                DishPropertyPriceType = option.DishPropertyPriceType,
                                                                DishPropertyRequired = option.DishPropertyRequired,
                                                                Id = option.Id,
                                                                MenuDishProperties = new List<MenuDishPropertyVM>()
                                                            };

                                                            menuById = new();
                                                            menuById.MenuDishPropertiesGroupID = Convert.ToInt32(option.Id);
                                                            properties = common.CreatePropertyList(menuById);
                                                            var MenuDishPropertiesList = await fireStoreHelper.getDocumentList<ModelLibrary.FireStore.MenuDishProperties>(collectionNames.MenuDishProperties, properties);
                                                            if (MenuDishPropertiesList != null && MenuDishPropertiesList.Count > 0)
                                                            {
                                                                foreach (var dish in MenuDishPropertiesList.OrderBy(x => x.DisplayoOder))
                                                                {
                                                                    NewProModel.OptionItem.MenuDishProperties.Add(new MenuDishPropertyVM()
                                                                    {
                                                                        DishProperty = dish.DishProperty,
                                                                        DishPropertyPrice = dish.DishPropertyPrice,
                                                                        DisplayoOder = dish.DisplayoOder,
                                                                        Id = dish.Id,
                                                                        MenuDishPropertiesGroupId = dish.MenuDishPropertiesGroupId
                                                                    });
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                    else
                                                    {
                                                        var MenuToppingsGroupsList = await fireStoreHelper.getDocumentList<ModelLibrary.FireStore.MenuToppingsGroups>(collectionNames.MenuToppingsGroups);
                                                        MenuToppingsGroups? option = new();
                                                        if (MenuToppingsGroupsList != null && MenuToppingsGroupsList.Count > 0)
                                                            option = MenuToppingsGroupsList.Where(x => x.Id == meniItemProModel.ItemId).First();
                                                        if (option != null)
                                                        {
                                                            NewProModel.ExtraItem = new MenuToppingsGroupVM()
                                                            {
                                                                BusinessDetailId = option.BusinessDetailId,
                                                                Id = option.Id,
                                                                MenuToppings = new List<MenuToppingVM>(),
                                                                ToppingsGoupDisplayName = option.ToppingsGoupDisplayName
                                                            };

                                                            menuById = new();
                                                            menuById.MenuToppingsGroupId = Convert.ToInt32(option.Id);
                                                            properties = common.CreatePropertyList(menuById);
                                                            var MenuToppingsList = await fireStoreHelper.getDocumentList<ModelLibrary.FireStore.MenuToppings>(collectionNames.MenuToppings, properties);
                                                            if (MenuToppingsList != null && MenuToppingsList.Count > 0)
                                                            {
                                                                foreach (var dish in MenuToppingsList.OrderBy(x => x.DisplayOrder))
                                                                {
                                                                    NewProModel.ExtraItem.MenuToppings.Add(new MenuToppingVM()
                                                                    {
                                                                        Id = dish.Id,
                                                                        MenuToppingsGroupId = dish.MenuToppingsGroupId,
                                                                        Topping = dish.Topping,
                                                                        ToppingPrice = dish.ToppingPrice
                                                                    });
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                    newmenuItemPro.MenuItemPropertyModels.Add(NewProModel);
                                                }
                                                newmenuItem.MenuItemProperties.Add(newmenuItemPro);
                                            }

                                            var MenuItemModelsList = await GetMenuItemModels(menuItem.Id);

                                            if (MenuItemModelsList != null && MenuItemModelsList.Count > 0)
                                            {
                                                foreach (var meniItemModel in MenuItemModelsList.Where(x => x.MenuItemId == menuItem.Id).OrderBy(x => x.DisplayOrder))
                                                {
                                                    var NewProModel = new MenuItemModelVM()
                                                    {
                                                        DisplayOrder = meniItemModel.DisplayOrder,
                                                        Id = meniItemModel.Id,
                                                        ItemId = meniItemModel.ItemId,
                                                        MenuItemId = meniItemModel.MenuItemId,
                                                        ItemType = meniItemModel.ItemType,
                                                        Label = meniItemModel.Label,
                                                        MaxQty = meniItemModel.MaxQty,
                                                        MaxSelectionPerItem = meniItemModel.MaxSelectionPerItem,
                                                        MinQty = meniItemModel.MinQty,
                                                        Name = meniItemModel.Name

                                                    };
                                                    if (NewProModel.ItemType == "Option")
                                                    {
                                                        if (MenuDishPropertiesGroupList == null && MenuDishPropertiesGroupList.Count == 0)
                                                        {
                                                            MenuDishPropertiesGroupList = await fireStoreHelper.getDocumentList<ModelLibrary.FireStore.MenuDishPropertiesGroups>(collectionNames.MenuDishPropertiesGroups);
                                                        }
                                                        var option = MenuDishPropertiesGroupList.Where(x => x.Id == meniItemModel.ItemId).First();
                                                        if (option != null)
                                                        {
                                                            NewProModel.OptionItem = new MenuDishPropertiesGroupVM()
                                                            {
                                                                BusinessDetailId = option.BusinessDetailId,
                                                                DishPropertyGroup = option.DishPropertyGroup,
                                                                DishPropertyGroupDisplayName = option.DishPropertyGroupDisplayName,
                                                                DishPropertyPriceType = option.DishPropertyPriceType,
                                                                DishPropertyRequired = option.DishPropertyRequired,
                                                                Id = option.Id,
                                                                MenuDishProperties = new List<MenuDishPropertyVM>()
                                                            };
                                                            menuById = new();
                                                            menuById.MenuDishPropertiesGroupID = Convert.ToInt32(option.Id);
                                                            properties = common.CreatePropertyList(menuById);
                                                            var MenuDishPropertiesList = await fireStoreHelper.getDocumentList<ModelLibrary.FireStore.MenuDishProperties>(collectionNames.MenuDishProperties, properties);

                                                            foreach (var dish in MenuDishPropertiesList.OrderBy(x => x.DisplayoOder))
                                                            {
                                                                NewProModel.OptionItem.MenuDishProperties.Add(new MenuDishPropertyVM()
                                                                {
                                                                    DishProperty = dish.DishProperty,
                                                                    DishPropertyPrice = dish.DishPropertyPrice,
                                                                    DisplayoOder = dish.DisplayoOder,
                                                                    Id = dish.Id,
                                                                    MenuDishPropertiesGroupId = dish.MenuDishPropertiesGroupId
                                                                });
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                    else
                                                    {
                                                        var MenuToppingsGroupsList = await fireStoreHelper.getDocumentList<ModelLibrary.FireStore.MenuToppingsGroups>(collectionNames.MenuToppingsGroups);
                                                        var option = MenuToppingsGroupsList.Where(x => x.Id == meniItemModel.ItemId).First();
                                                        if (option != null)
                                                        {
                                                            NewProModel.ExtraItem = new MenuToppingsGroupVM()
                                                            {
                                                                BusinessDetailId = option.BusinessDetailId,
                                                                Id = option.Id,
                                                                MenuToppings = new List<MenuToppingVM>(),
                                                                ToppingsGoupDisplayName = option.ToppingsGoupDisplayName

                                                            };
                                                            menuById = new();
                                                            menuById.MenuToppingsGroupId = Convert.ToInt32(option.Id);
                                                            properties = common.CreatePropertyList(menuById);
                                                            var MenuToppingsList = await fireStoreHelper.getDocumentList<ModelLibrary.FireStore.MenuToppings>(collectionNames.MenuToppings, properties);
                                                            foreach (var dish in MenuToppingsList)
                                                            {
                                                                NewProModel.ExtraItem.MenuToppings.Add(new MenuToppingVM()
                                                                {
                                                                    Id = dish.Id,
                                                                    MenuToppingsGroupId = dish.MenuToppingsGroupId,
                                                                    Topping = dish.Topping,
                                                                    ToppingPrice = dish.ToppingPrice
                                                                });
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                    newmenuItem.MenuItemModels.Add(NewProModel);
                                                }
                                                menuCategory.MenuItems.Add(newmenuItem);
                                            }
                                        }
                                        ret.Add(menuCategory);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        status = HttpStatus.OK;
                        var rootResponse = new rootResponse();
                        rootResponse.Status = (int)status;
                        rootResponse.menuCategories = ret;
                        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rootResponse);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return NotFoundResponse();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return NotFoundResponse();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return UnauthorizedResponse();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return InternalServerError(ex);
        }
    }
 
    #region optimized code

    private async Task<List<ModelLibrary.FireStore.MenuCategories>> GetMenuCategories(int? businessDetailId)
    {
        byBusiness = new() { BusinessDetailId = businessDetailId };
        properties = common.CreatePropertyList(byBusiness);
        return await fireStoreHelper.getDocumentList<ModelLibrary.FireStore.MenuCategories>(collectionNames.MenuCategories, properties);
    }

    private async Task<List<ModelLibrary.FireStore.MenuItems>> GetMenuItems(int categoryId)
    {
        var menuById = new GETMenuById() { MenuCategoryId = categoryId };
        properties = common.CreatePropertyList(menuById);
        return await fireStoreHelper.getDocumentList<ModelLibrary.FireStore.MenuItems>(collectionNames.MenuItems, properties);
    }

    private async Task<List<ModelLibrary.FireStore.MenuItemProperties>> GetMenuItemProperties(int menuItemId)
    {
        var menuById = new GETMenuById() { IdMenuItem = menuItemId };
        properties = common.CreatePropertyList(menuById);
        return await fireStoreHelper.getDocumentList<ModelLibrary.FireStore.MenuItemProperties>(collectionNames.MenuItemProperties, properties);
    }
    private async Task<List<ModelLibrary.FireStore.MenuItemPropertyModels>> GetMenuItemPropertyModels(int menuItemPropertyId)
    {
        var menuById = new GETMenuById() { MenuItemPropertyId = menuItemPropertyId };
        properties = common.CreatePropertyList(menuById);
        return await fireStoreHelper.getDocumentList<ModelLibrary.FireStore.MenuItemPropertyModels>(collectionNames.MenuItemPropertyModels, properties);
    }
    private async Task<List<ModelLibrary.FireStore.MenuItemModels>> GetMenuItemModels(int menuItemId)
    {
        var menuById = new GETMenuById() { MenuItemId = menuItemId };
        properties = common.CreatePropertyList(menuById);
        return await fireStoreHelper.getDocumentList<ModelLibrary.FireStore.MenuItemModels>(collectionNames.MenuItemModels, properties);
    }

    #endregion


    private string InternalServerError(Exception ex)
    {
        status = HttpStatus.InternalServerError;
        var rootException = new rootExceptionStatus();
        rootException.Status = (int)status;
        rootException.message = "Something went wrong please try again";
        rootException.exmessage = ex.Message;
        rootException.stackTrace = ex.StackTrace;
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rootException);
    }
    private string UnauthorizedResponse()
    {
        status = HttpStatus.Unauthorized;
        var root = new rootStatus();
        root.Status = (int)status;
        root.message = "Unauthorized";
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root);
    }
    private string NotFoundResponse()
    {
        status = HttpStatus.NotFound;
        var root = new rootStatus();
        root.Status = (int)status;
        root.message = "record not found";
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root);
    }
    private class rootStatus
    {
        public int Status { get; set; }
        public string? message { get; set; }
    }
    private class rootResponse
    {
        public int Status { get; set; }
        public List<MenuCategoryVM>? menuCategories { get; set; }
    }
    private class rootExceptionStatus
    {
        public int Status { get; set; }
        public string? message { get; set; }
        public string? exmessage { get; set; }
        public string? stackTrace { get; set; }
    }
}


Is this a UI?  I'm no C# expert but the number of Menu related things makes me think you're trying to run a UI in a headless environment.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

@stdunbar this is c# code which is getting data from bd and i want to display in ui my issue is the code is not optimized which i need to do and I'm stocked in it to do optimized and database is used firebased
